# Google Api: Unable to fetch updated profiles using "updated-min"

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I tried to fetched updated user profiles of the users in my domain using the "updated-min" query parameter, but still I got the list of all the users from the domain, I have used the below URL for the same:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/DomainName/full?updated-min=2012-08-24T00:00:00&access_token="+access_token+"&v=3.0"

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the updated-min parameter does not work with the profile data api.  It only works with the Contact API. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters

If you take a look at the documentation, you can see that it is supported for Contact APi.  But it doesn't mention the support for Profile data api anywhere in the documentation.